# using build in has_many relationship in create action results in mass assignment error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, mass-assignment

I have a mass assignment error I can only fix with UGLY code. I must be doing something wrong.
Let me explain:

I my rails application clients have many contacts. The Client page shows a list of contacts belonging to that client.
I want to be able to add a new contact to the list. So I pass the client to the contact controller using...

```
<%= link_to('new contact', new_contact_path(client_id: @client)) %>
```

In the ContactsController....

```
def new
 client=Client.find(params[:client_id])
 @contact=client.contacts.new
end


def create
  @client = Client.find(params[:contact][:client_id])
  @contact= @client.contacts.build(params[:contact])
      if @contact.save
 ...
```

The 'save' results in an unsurprising error:

> Can't mass-assign protected attributes: client_id

because the contact params include the client_id which is not (and should not be) attr_accessible in the contact model

The only way I know how to fix the problem is to set every parameter individually (excluding the client_id) as follows:

```
@contact= @client.contacts.build(first_name: params[:contact][:first_name], last_name:     params[:contact][:first_name], email: params[:contact][:email])
```

This approach works but it just all seems wrong. Surely is some more elegant alternative. 
Any help is appreciated. 
(yes i am new to rails)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To skip the part to tell you how you should fix your error, I would like to tell you how you should do the coding in the first place :) Correct if I am wrong.

In `Routes.rb` you should have put(if not so already):

```
resources :client do
    resources : contacts
end
```

Then, second in you `view` file you should put something like this:

```
<%= link_to('new contact', new_client_contact_path(@client)) %>
```

In that way, you don't have to do anything in your create action, rails will manage all other things.
That is the way it is supposed to be done

Edit:

just to make it more clear.
In `new` action in your `contacts` controller you should put:

```
user= user.find(params[:user_id])
#2nd you build a new one
@contact= user.contacts.build
```

And in your `create` action in `contacts` controller , you should put:

```
user = User.find(params[:user_id])
#2nd you create the contact with arguments in params[:contact ]
@contact = user.contact.create(params[:contact ])
response .....
```

Comment: thanks...I was pretty sure I was trying to work around the problem the wrong way. It seems like a pretty common scenario

Comment: Yes it is. I have added code for new and create actions (I have done it without testing so something might be wrong if just copy-paste). But yes it is common. If you want to look around more, look for `nested resources` and how to use them. Glad it helped. Thanks

Comment: Later I learned about accepts_nested_attributes_for and found a much better way of creating contacts